# NoClassDefFoundError while creating AmazonSNSClient using AWS SDK for Java

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, noclassdeffounderror, amazon-sns

In my Android app I want to work with Amazon SNS

```
AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
```

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient
```

I use Eclipse Luna and installed AWS Toolkit for Eclipse.
In Java Build Path of my Project, I selected "Add Library" -> "AWS SDK for Java".

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me!

Comment: Have you written an `import` statement for that package and class?

Comment: @deepu513  What do you mean? This line "import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;" ? Of course yes.

Comment: The error is on that line only, it is not able to import the SDK.

Comment: @deepu513 I don't understand the problem. What is the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: Go to your project folder and then search for "libs" folder, it might be inside the app directory or build directory and paste your jar file there and restart eclipse.

Comment: It doesn't work. It even crash my Eclipse.

Comment: It used to work for me when i used eclipse. try searching then how to add library in eclipse, may be the way you are adding doesn't work.

Comment: @deepu513 I used to add libraries to Eclipse project, but only this time it doesn't work. Maybe there is something wrong with Amazon Library. Anyway, thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has an SDK specifically for Android https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/.

A getting started guide, including how to set up in Eclipse (Or use Android Studio / Maven) is available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html.

I also highly suggest not embedding credentials in your application when releasing it, as it is highly insecure and anyone could decompile your app and steal your credentials.  Instead I suggest looking at Amazon Cognito for authentication (it's in the guide linked above).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.   I have to create a credentials: AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey). Should I hide the accessKey and secretKey and how?

Comment: Instead of using BasicAWSCredentials, use CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.  It requires you to set up a a Cognito Identity Pool on the console.  Instructions can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html#step-3-get-aws-credentials.  Glad your making progress!